# Is it possible to select multiple edge-loops simultaneously?

Tags: edges, edit-mode

I'm trying to select multiple edge loops by just doing one of them.

[image]

I want to know if there's a faster way of selection rather than doing it one by one. If there is a way, does the symmetry plays a role in terms of selection?

Comment: In this particular case you could use "Select Non Manifold" operator Shift + Ctrl + Alt + M  with only the option "Boundaries" ticked, though it will also select the outer boundary. Deselecting it is still less work than selecting four loops though.

Comment: There are actually more loops than is shown in the image. I used the circular region select tool to deselect the undesired area. Thank you.

Comment: You can alsoa use  Alt + RightMouse button and  Shift + Alt + RightMouse button by default to toggle select/deselect a whole loop

Comment: yes, just hold ctrl+alt and click on the edge loops.

Comment: you can select the edges that are part of a loop one by one and then do a 'edge loop select'

Answer (score 1):

There is another way,which is selection by similarity.

The loops you are trying to select are similar in length for instance.

Select the loop and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> , **Length**.

[image: Select similar]

You may want to decrease the threshold if your want a more precise result.